# Hard Drive Not Cooperating

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I've run a live Disk Verification and "restore" on my Macbook and it prompts that my disc cannot be repaired. I have tried to "partition" but have close to no idea how to do it effectively and my files are not backed up. I have tried to reinstall Lion on my computer, but it came with the laptop when I bought it and I don't know if it is legal because the "reinstall" portion just keeps telling me to "Contact Apple" (though I no longer have Apple Care).

Is there *anything* I can do to save my files from being lost in the possibly corrupted hard drive?

I appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try stand-alone Clonezilla 2.0.1. You would be surprised as to how great tool it is (very bad walk through the screens, though).

Not only you will be using a free tool that is used by Taiwan Super Computing Center, but by millions of users.

Only negative is that the screen and language usage is not typical American English, per se.

You will need to burn approx 150MB ISO file (using ImgBurn, MagicISO, etc..)

LINKS:
http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=clonezilla
http://www.clonezilla.org/downloads/stable/iso-zip-files.php

http://www.filehippo.com/software/dvd/